# что делает [RequireContext(ContextType.Guild)]

Tags: c#

объясните что делает данная строка кода [RequireContext(ContextType.Guild)] и зачем её применять библеотека discord.net [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Читать [документацию](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Commands.RequireContextAttribute.html) я так понимаю уже не модно? Этот атрибут задает от куда бот будет реагировать на сообщение (канал, сервер, личное сообщение). Советую в дальнейшем искать самостоятельно, а не просить у сторонних помощи по каждому чиху. Ответ можете оформить сами.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо большое за ответ, я читал документацию но я почему-то данный аспект упустил у себя в голове .